# Roslyn compiler in one central location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, roslyn

With every publish of a MVC site, the roslyn compilers are also placed in the BIN folder.
Is it possible to put roslyn in one location and have every website refer to it?
It would save up some diskspace.

Comment: It's 2020. Is disk space really a high concern for you? The trend has been long heading towards giving each application as much independence as possible, the opposite direction from sharing component binaries.

Comment: Have you tried [pre-compiling the views](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/698/aspnet-mvc-compiled-views), instead? Besides the space saving, you get increased security and reliability.

Comment: Precompile is not an option as we use partial views.